# How to parse an Oracle 11g query in Java and produce JSON as output

Tags: java, sql, json, parsing

I have to parse a Oracle 11g SQL query (query contains joins, In, colase, sub-queries and aggregate functions) and produce a JSON String as a result of paring it. I am using Java 8 and would like to know any free libraries that can help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Comment: This is waaaay too vague have you done any research or tried anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Give some examples: SQL, expected result? What do you have so far? To parse a SQL e.g. JSqlParser can be used. As the maintainer I suggest the fork at gitbub ;).

Comment: [See also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55188631/521799)

Answer (score 0):

If you know what columns are returned, then create a pojo with these columns and use Jackson library to convert the result set to JSON.