# Json representation of SQL conditions

Tags: java, sql, json

Is there any method to convert a SQL condition to Json? I mean, I need to write something like this:

```
x > 5 and (y like '%b%' or z > 5) and b = true
```

as Json?

Comment: What would this mean? JSON is a format for communicating an object, with properties. There are lots of ways you could communicate this information as JSON, but it would be up to the recipient to decode it into the expression.

Comment: Find a SQL parser, parse the SQL in question and convert the predicate portion of the AST into a JSON array.

Comment: try tsql-parser https://github.com/bruce-dunwiddie/tsql-parser/blob/master/TSQL_Parser/Tests/Statements/SelectStatementTests.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for that. Here's a quick and dirty example of how that could work:

```java
new Gson()
    .newBuilder()
    .setPrettyPrinting()
    // Some jOOQ types can be serialised out of the box
    // For others, you might have to register adapters explicitly:
    .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(
       Field.class, 
       (JsonSerializer<Field<?>>) (s, t, ctx) -> new JsonPrimitive(s.getName()))
    .create()
    .toJson(DSL.using(SQLDialect.DEFAULT)
       .parser()
       .parseCondition("x > 5 and (y like '%b%' or z > 5) and b = true"), 
       System.out
    );
```

The above prints:

```js
{
  "operator": "AND",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "field1": "X",
      "field2": "5",
      "comparator": "GREATER"
    },
    {
      "operator": "OR",
      "conditions": [
        {
          "field1": "Y",
          "field2": "%b%",
          "comparator": "LIKE"
        },
        {
          "field1": "Z",
          "field2": "5",
          "comparator": "GREATER"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "field1": "B",
      "field2": "true",
      "comparator": "EQUALS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, this is not very forward compatible, because it uses reflection to access jOOQ's internals. The names of your JSON objects (e.g. `operator`, `conditions`) might change at any time, but it may still be good enough for you.

A future jOOQ version might offer more stable JSON exports of its expression tree:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9628

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.

Comment: Thank you. Looks interesting. But I wonder about types of values. All of them are converted to string.

Comment: @ks099: This is the canonical output of Gson. It's not unlikely you can tweak the output in any way you want. I mean, it's not like your question had any highly specific requirements, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found and used JsonLogic. It is very good approach as well.
https://jsonlogic.com/